# I am trying to connect IBMMQ with my spring boot application but the connection should be through spid(pki). any one have some idea how to do?

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-mq, pki, java-ee-8

I am trying to write a spring boot program which will connect to existing ibmMQ. But the pain is it should be done through spid(pki) certificate. I don't know how to do that. Please help me..

Comment: What have you tried?  What is not working?

Comment: Hello, your question have a terrible lack of information, but I can give you a few clues. Certificate authentication for MQ is done based on the certificate content (e.g : CN=MyServer, ...) So you have to provide a certificate matching this definition. You also have to define the CYPHER_SUIT and the keystore (with keytool from IBM) on client side. You have everything in this answer, you just need to find how to do it ^^